# Using functions from a module that requires variables from a config file

Tags: python

There are three main files in my code:

- `config.yml`: contains connection address, ports, and so on.
- modules > `fetchers.py`: contains different fetching functions that fetches different content from apis that requires connection info from the `config.yml`
- `main.py`: uses fetchers' functions

What I am currently doing is, the `main.py` reads `config.yml` to get connection info, and passes connection info as params to the fetchers function every time.

However, I am thinking if I could let the `fetchers.py` to read and get the connection info, so that I could avoid passing bunch of params everytime I calls those fetchers function. If by doing so, will the `fetchers.py` reads config file whenever I calls its functions? Does that means if I called twice, the config file will be read twice and made extra costs of disk IO?

Comment: You could create a config class which can read and store all settings. Then "main.py" creates a config object, triggers loading data and can pass this single object to the fetcher functions when calling them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the functions in `fetchers.py` read the configuration. Code on module-level is usually executed just once but if you would e.g. read the config files within the functions it would of course read them every time.

I would still highly recommend to keep configuration management (e.g. loading them from a file) and functions that work with that configuration separate. `NamedTuple` classes are e.g. an easy way to group several function arguments regarding configuration into one.